# How to assess predictive validity of a variable on the outcome?

Tags: odds-ratio, validity

I am looking to assess the predictive validity of two measures (M1 and M2) on a binary outcome. After constructing my model, do I just calculate odds ratios and compare the odds ratios for the two measures?

Comment: What do you mean by predictive validity? There are several options: AUC, Brier-score, Sensitivity vs specifitity plot, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to see if M1 or M2 predicts the outcome better. I though AUC was to assess the validity of the model rather than specific variables within the model

Comment: Yes, it is global metric. So you want to compare if other variable is more powerful than other in some sense? What are their measurement units, that affects things?

Comment: yes that is what I want to do. The measurement units differ with one being categorical (0, 1, 2) and the other being count (1-27).

Comment: I think it will be quite different to have a change from category value 0 to 1 than to move one unit upwards in scale of your continuous variable...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional info.

Now I can only suggest you to use likelihood ratio based test where change in the LR statistic without other variable is the interesting outcome.